# iMac 24", 2nd monitor 90 degree rotation

Tags: macos, mac

I can not get the display settings to hold for my second monitor. I set it for a 90 degree rotation, portrait, and after a reboot it goes back to standard. I am running 10.5.8 Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

OS X is not very kind for portrait modes. Guess the easiest workaround is to record an Apple script, save it as application, and put it in the startup items.